# Elgato Wave 3 only as input or output but not both

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

I was not able to find anything similar to this, so I hope this is not a duplicated question...

I have the following issue with my Elgato Wave 3 microphone: when I want to use it as an input (microphone), it works like a charm, but when I connect the headphones at the back of it, using it also as an output (selecting it on settings panel or PulseAudio control), the microphone stops registering as an input, so I cannot use it anymore as a microphone, but headphones works...

I saw that it could have missing the `output + input` or `duplex` profile or something related to the profile, but I have no idea if I can add it or what can I do to solve this. I tried researching about `pactl` but I do not understand it fully.

The profiles I see are:

1. Analog Stereo Output
2. Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
3. Analog Mono Input
4. Off

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Solved this and tested through Zoom recordings.

Currently on Pop Os - 20.10 Using Generic Pulse Mixer

1. Open Pulse Audio Volume Mixer
2. Go to Configuration Tab
3. Elgato Wave 3 device DropSelect -> "Analog Stereo Output + Multichannel Input"
4. Input Devices Tab > Elgato Wave 3 Multichannel -> Port: Select Multichannel Input
5. Output Tab > Elgato Wave:3 Analog Stereo -> Port:  Analog Output.
6. Adjust controls physical on the device to suit input gain, output and Crossover to taste.

You may need to select "Show : All devices" if not showing up the first time, at the bottom of the mixer window.

You may need to restart Pulse Audio via the terminal with

`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`

If your device is not seen.

Have a test call and record it. Hope it helps others.

Comment: My main problem is that I do not see "Analog Stereo Output + Multichannel Input", I only see Output or Input. I will have a look in a few minutes and reply. But I am using 20.04, not 20.10 and I will not leave LTS, I will still give it a new try !

Comment: I had to choose "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Multichannel Input" in step 3 and then it all worked.